# How to find out which variable is throwing an exception?

Tags: java

I'm writing a program that culculates tip and total from bill and tip rate.

```
public void takeUserInput() {
    Scanner sc = new Scanner(System.in);    
    double billAmount;
    int tipRate;

    try {
        System.out.print("What is the bill? ");
        billAmount = sc.nextDouble();
        System.out.print("What is the tip percentage? ");
        tipRate = sc.nextInt();

        tc.calculate(billAmount, tipRate);
    } catch (InputMismatchException e1) {
        String errorMessage = "Please enter a valid number for the ";
        // errorMessage += billAmount or
        // errorMessage += tipRate ?
    }
```

I'm looking for a way to find out which variable throws InputMismatchException, so I can add which variable name into variable errorMessage and print to the screen.

Comment: @Andreas I know that method, but I need which variable name.

Comment: Neither would throw that exception if you just checked for validity before calling `nextXxx()`, using `hasNextXxx()`.

Comment: @Andreas I don't use loop statements.

Comment: Where in that previous comment did I say anything about loops?

Comment: @Andreas I'm sorry I knew that method is only used in loop.

Comment: Then you "knew" wrong. The `hasNextXxx()` methods can be used before any `nextXxx()` method to pre-check validity of input. What you do when finding bad input is entirely up to you. The use of `hasNextXxx()` vs catching `InputMismatchException` is entirely independent of whether or not you loop back to prompt again.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The variable isn't throwing the exception, the evaluation of the right hand side of the variable assignment is, and so there is no information in the exception to say which variable it was about to assign that to had it succeeded.

What you could consider instead is a new method that encompasses the prompting messages and retries:

```
billAmount = doubleFromUser(sc, "What is the bill? ", "bill");
```

Where `doubleFromUser` is:

```
static double doubleFromUser(Scanner sc, String prompt, String description){
    while(true) { //until there is a successful input
        try {
            System.out.print(prompt); //move to before the loop if you do not want this repeated
            return sc.nextDouble();
        } catch (InputMismatchException e1) {
            System.out.println("Please enter a valid number for the " + description);
        }
    }
}
```

You will need a different one for int and double, but if you have more prompts, you will save in the long run.

Answer (score 1):

There are various simple ways to get there:

1. Call **hasNextXxx()** prior calling **nextXxx()**.
2. If you go for **one** try/catch block per input, it is very clear within your catch block which variable caused the problem (you could then call a generic method with a specific error message to avoid code duplication)
3. You could use **reference** types for your variables; if you use Double / Integer instead of double / int ... you could check which of the two variables is still **null**
4. You put in a little boolean variable, like `billAmountIsValid`. Initially that variable is false, you turn it to true after the call to nextDouble(). Then you can easily check in your try block whether you got a valid billAmount.

After some more thinking: you really want a combination of 1 + 2: you see; when the users enters a correct billAmount; why would you want to **forget** about that value when the second value gives a bad second value? No - you should be **looping** for each variable, until you receive a **valid** input. And only then you start asking for the next value!

Comment: 4. Call `hasNextXxx()` before `nextXxx()`.

Comment: Thanks. Nice idea; added that to the list as first entry!

Comment: See the following for why **not using exceptions** (option 1) may be the better solution: [Are exceptions as control flow considered a serious antipattern? If so, Why?](http://programmers.stackexchange.com/q/189222/202153)

Comment: @Andreas Thank you, I didn't know that way would be antipattern.

Comment: @GhostCat I solved with weston's answer. I'm sorry. For now his way is easy to me.

Comment: Never mind. I guess you got something useful out of my answer... And sometimes that is good enough!